# Convert scalar values from record batch to hex string using pyarrow

Tags: python, pyarrow

I want to convert scalar values from record batch to hex string, but the method I use is very inefficient.Here is the operation:

```
data = [
        pyarrow.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
        pyarrow.array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', None]),
        pyarrow.array([True, None, False, True])
    ]
batch = pyarrow.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, ['f0', 'f1', 'f2'])

hex_index = [0,1]

hex_list = []

for i in range(0,3):
  values = [str(batch[idx][i].as_py().encode('utf-8') for idx in hex_index]
  hl = hashlib.blake2b()
  for v in values:
      hl.update(v)
  hex_list.append(hl.hexdigest())
```

Is there any other methods to improve efficiency? Or is there any pyarrow api to convert pyarrow scalar value to bytes?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve? Are you calcualting the hash of each row?

Comment: yes, I am calcualting the hash of each row. I have adjust the code.